# Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send the notification to devices within a circle of a radius of a point using firebase cloud functions. I am able to get the id of the devices within the circle but I am not able to get the token, the token is null as printed using console.log(token).

```
     const getdevicetokenpromise = db.ref('/DriversAvailable/{key}/token').once('value');
     console.log(key); //this value is right

    return getdevicetokenpromise.then(result => {
        console.log(result.val());   //this value is null, this is the problem
        var token = result.val();
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'title',
                body: 'hey, well done dude',
                icon: 'default'

                }
            };



        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
        .then((response)=> {
        return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

    });
```

I have tried most of the things suggested on stackoverflow but coudln't find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that the value of `key` should be inserted into this string:

```
 const getdevicetokenpromise = db.ref('/DriversAvailable/{key}/token').once('value');
```

That's not the way it's working, though.  You are literally querying for that exact string, without `key` being inserted.  I imagine you meant to use JavaScript syntax for variable interpolation using backticks around the string and ${} to delimit the variable:

```
 const getdevicetokenpromise = db.ref(`/DriversAvailable/${key}/token`).once('value');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was working on it for hours.

Comment: Good to heard.  If you found this answer correct, please accept it as the correct answer.